# Gradient-based saliency of input words in a pytorch model from transformers library

Tags: pytorch, gradient, huggingface-transformers

The following code is used to determine the impact of input words on the most probable output unit.

```
def _register_embedding_list_hook(model, embeddings_list):
    def forward_hook(module, inputs, output):
        embeddings_list.append(output.squeeze(0).clone().cpu().detach().numpy())
    embedding_layer = model.bert.embeddings.word_embeddings
    handle = embedding_layer.register_forward_hook(forward_hook)
    return handle

def _register_embedding_gradient_hooks(model, embeddings_gradients):
    def hook_layers(module, grad_in, grad_out):
        embeddings_gradients.append(grad_out[0])
    embedding_layer = model.bert.embeddings.word_embeddings
    hook = embedding_layer.register_backward_hook(hook_layers)
    return hook

def saliency_map(model, input_ids, segment_ids, input_mask):
    torch.enable_grad()
    model.eval()
    embeddings_list = []
    handle = _register_embedding_list_hook(model, embeddings_list)
    embeddings_gradients = []
    hook = _register_embedding_gradient_hooks(model, embeddings_gradients)

    model.zero_grad()
    A = model(input_ids, token_type_ids=segment_ids, attention_mask=input_mask)
    pred_label_ids = np.argmax(A.logits[0].detach().numpy())
    A.logits[0][pred_label_ids].backward()
    handle.remove()
    hook.remove()

    saliency_grad = embeddings_gradients[0].detach().cpu().numpy()        
    saliency_grad = np.sum(saliency_grad[0] * embeddings_list[0], axis=1)
    norm = np.linalg.norm(saliency_grad, ord=1)
    saliency_grad = [e / norm for e in saliency_grad] 
    
    return saliency_grad
```

which is used in the following way (for a sentiment analysis model):

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("textattack/bert-base-uncased-imdb")
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("textattack/bert-base-uncased-imdb")

tokens = tokenizer('A really bad movie')

input_ids = torch.tensor([tokens['input_ids']], dtype=torch.long)
token_type_ids = torch.tensor([tokens['token_type_ids']], dtype=torch.long)
attention_ids = torch.tensor([tokens['attention_mask']], dtype=torch.long)

saliency_scores = saliency_map(model, input_ids, 
                                token_type_ids, 
                                attention_ids)
```

But it produces the following scores for the tokens which are nonsense since for example "bad" has a negative effect on the predicted class (which is negative). What's wrong with this code?

[image]

Here are some more examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: So why are the scores nonsense?  The scores seem fine to me, the only thing that appears off is that you sum the gradients and then apply an L1 norm, which would not change anything, unless I'm missing something.

edit: if anything I'd say the score make perfect sense, the two most important tokens have the highest absolute scores

Comment: @user13392352 I added a better example (replacing "great" with "good").

Comment: So why are these scores are nonsense? Is the assumption that a high gradient = high importance? Have you got a paper you're basing this off, if so could you link it. The only thing I would say would be If I wanted to guess the importance of a word based off gradient I would simply takes it's L1 norm / absolute sum

Comment: @user13392352 It's a method known as "input x gradient" used in some papers like http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/shrikumar17a/shrikumar17a.pdf

Comment: the paper you linked just seemed to mention the overarching theory not really how to actually implement it. But if you were going for "input x gradient" shouldn't you just be doing `saliency_grad = [np.dot(e, e_g) for e, e_g in zip(embeddings_list, embeddings_gradients)]`

Comment: @user13392352 The code is adopted from the following link: https://github.com/xhan77/influence-function-analysis/blob/master/bert_util.py
It was meant to compute the saliency as `saliency_grad = np.sum(saliency_grad[0] * embeddings_list[0], axis=1)` before normalization. There was a mistake in pasting the code, which is now corrected. The example is also modified based on this correction, which is still nonsense.

Comment: could you make an image or show what you're expecting to see because from your example it still appears to be correct to me ("a" is scored very low, "really bad movie" are all scored high as swapping any out should give you a noticeable change in sentiment)

Comment: @user13392352 The problem is that "bad" has a negative effect on the predicted class (which is negative) while it should have a positive effect. I added some more examples to make the situation clear.

Comment: if it is supposed to work perfectly then I don't know, but if the assumption is that the decision plane in regards to the word embeddings is completely linear from the origin (zero vector), then I can see where this will fall flat. the word embeddings for "bad" and "good" are really close for most language models. To be able to account for this the model will have to be non-linear for these embeddings. A better test to see whether it's working may be to find a negative sentiment word which can't be replaced with a positive sentiment word and see if the scores are as you expect.

Comment: with regards to my last comment, if my suggestion at the bottom doesn't work then I'm stumped

Comment: @user13392352 Thanks for your response. I think it is supposed to work perfectly (showing a rational explanation of the model's behavior)